# Mp4 render result from ffmpeg not playable on android

Tags: php, android, ffmpeg

I'm using PHP to run ffmpeg(4.0.2) render out MP4 file.
MP4 file playable on all of iOS device, and most laptop, but not playable on android device.

Here is the ffmpeg code I use to render the video

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -filter_complex "[0]reverse[r];[0][r]concat, loop=1:65, setpts=N/15/TB" -r 15 -f image2 -i /Source/0001_CAM%02d.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 19 -profile:v baseline -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p /Result/output.mp4
```

Here is the log

```
[0] => ffmpeg version N-91590-geb1860e017-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
    [1] =>   built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
    [2] =>   configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
    [3] =>   libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
    [4] =>   libavcodec     58. 22.101 / 58. 22.101
    [5] =>   libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
    [6] =>   libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
    [7] =>   libavfilter     7. 26.100 /  7. 26.100
    [8] =>   libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
    [9] =>   libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
    [10] =>   libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
    [11] => Input #0, image2, from '/Source/0001_CAM%02d.jpg':
    [12] =>   Duration: 00:00:00.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    [13] =>     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3456x2304, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 15 tbc
    [14] => Stream mapping:
    [15] =>   Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> reverse
    [16] =>   Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> concat:in0:v0
    [17] =>   setpts -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
    [18] => Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [19] => [swscaler @ 0x1077f9000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    [20] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    [21] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] profile Constrained Baseline, level 5.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
    [22] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] 264 - core 157 r2932 303c484 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=15 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=19.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [23] => Output #0, mp4, to '/Result/output.mp4':
    [24] =>   Metadata:
    [25] =>     encoder         : Lavf58.17.101
    [26] =>     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3456x2304, q=-1--1, 15 fps, 15360 tbn, 15 tbc (default)
    [27] =>     Metadata:
    [28] =>       encoder         : Lavc58.22.101 libx264
    [29] =>     Side data:
    [30] =>       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    [31] => frame=    8 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
[mp4 @ 0x7fd583804a00] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
    [32] => frame=   20 fps=5.1 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10642kB time=00:00:01.26 bitrate=68823.6kbits/s speed=0.322x
    [33] => video:10641kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.009452%
    [34] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] frame I:4     Avg QP:17.92  size:895006
    [35] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] frame P:16    Avg QP:19.96  size:457246
    [36] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] mb I  I16..4: 11.5%  0.0% 88.5%
    [37] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] mb P  I16..4:  4.1%  0.0% 25.0%  P16..4: 27.7% 19.0%  6.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:17.3%
    [38] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 92.9% 89.0% 56.0% inter: 51.3% 65.2% 3.9%
    [39] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 28%  5% 14% 52%
    [40] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 12% 15%  8%  9% 10%  7%  8%  6%
    [41] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 47% 16% 29%  8%
    [42] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] ref P L0: 81.6% 18.4%
    [43] => [libx264 @ 0x7fd583800600] kb/s:65375.79
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: @llogan I already add the log